# MySQL Duplicate primary key on unexisting key

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I've got a weird problem on a `MySQL` table. When trying to insert a new row, it says the primary key is duplicate. My primary key is auto incremental and is not set within my query (automatically set by MySQL).

The problem is I get a "Duplicate primary key" error on a key that doesn't even exists (I checked). I solved the problem increasing the current `auto_increment` value but I can't understand how it happened.

Any help would be great.

**Edit**

Table creation

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_mvt` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ext_article_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `date_mvt` date NOT NULL,
  `qte` float(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `in_out` enum('in','out') NOT NULL,
  `ext_nateco_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `ext_agent_id` int(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Demandeur',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1647 ;
```

Problematic query

```
INSERT INTO articles_mvt (
        `ext_article_id`,
        `date_mvt`,
        `qte`,
        `in_out`,
        `ext_nateco_id`,
        `ext_agent_id`
    )
    VALUES (
        '".$_POST["numArticle"]."',
        '".dateSql($_POST["date_mvt"])."',
        ".$_POST["qte_entier"].".".$_POST["qte_virgule"].",
        '".$_POST["in_out"]."',
        ".$_POST["numNateco"].",
        ".$_POST["demandeur"]."
    )
```

FYI variables are sanitized earlier in the code ;)

Comment: we can't help you if you dont post your query...

Answer (score 0):

Well i think at that time you did not check auto Inc flag on primary key. So when you try to enter than value 0 is insert in the primary key and for second entry it gives error. like that

```
ID Value 
0   A    ok it not give error
0  ff    it gives error..
```

Or you may try to insert a row whose ID is already exist like

```
ID Value 
11   A    ok it not give error
11  ff    it gives error..
```

Comment: The primary key is auto incremental

Comment: is your table syntex is like that DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Table`;
CREATE TABLE  `Table` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: you had used AUTO_INCREMENT=1647 in the table. Please make sure your table data did not contains id greater than 1647. otherwise your table structure is fine. Just check your max id value by using query like select Max(id) from `articles_mvt`;

Comment: I did. When the problem occured the auto_increment was 1601 and my highest id in the row was 1599...